# change the roi (region of image ) of image_1 with the an image without losing the other pixels in image_1

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

[image of pant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuRO2.png) [x1,x2,y1,y2 is the coordinat of the legs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr3Iw.png)
       `pantalon_end = PANTALON[x11:y11,x22:y22]
       pantalon_end = cv2.resize(pantalon_end,(59,76))
       avatar_end = AVATAR
       avatar_end2 = avatar_end[x1:y1,x2:y2] = pantalon_end`

in the code i the others pixels in the AVATAR image how i can save the other pixels and change the area (x1:y1,x2:y2)

Comment: it will help people on this website provide you with a good answer if you can post the original image and what your above code does to that image and what you would prefer the output to look like

Comment: thank you for your advise i edited it and i put the two images on the top of the question

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear what your goal is. Do you want to overlay the pants on the avatar?

Comment: yes i want to overlay the pant on the avatar legs i get the bounding box coordinat of the legs and the pant .

Comment: Thank you, i think you miss understand me i have two images .